# How to debug why my Python bottle web service return no response

Tags: python, server, connection, bottle

I built a micro web service using Python with bottle.py as the framework. The service simply read/write to a text file. I deploy it to a AWS Linux server, but I always find it stops working two or three days later - timed out when trying to open it from browser. I don't see any errors in the logs. At this moment it's not working again, so I log into the server and I see the process is still running fine, it's using 16 MB of memory which is correct. I can even `ping 0.0.0.0` and it's giving me response. But when I try to visit it from the browser, the connection just times out. The file that's being read/write looks fine too.

On the server if I do `curl 0.0.0.0` or `curl localhost`, it also just waits forever. I know when the process was working fine, this command should be able to get me right response.

I can do some health check and restart the process once it failed the check, but I'd really like to find out what's going on.

Comment: Add lots of log statements to your code, and then look at the log file to see which statements are being logged and which aren't.  That will at least tell you how much of the code (if any) is being executed before it hangs.

Comment: @JohnGordon Good idea, I'll probably have to do that to find out since there's nothing else I can do. So weird...

Comment: This is a wild guess, but it sounds like you might have a loop that gets out of control.  i.e. something like `for x in range(y)` where y starts out small but eventually increases to a huge number.  If you have any loops in your code, I would definitely want to log the upper bound before iterating.

Comment: Are you using a concurrent backend server (like `gevent`)?  If not, are you sure the request thread isn't deadlocked on some operation?  E.g. are you making any HTTP calls with no timeout set?

Comment: Once your server stops responding, do you see subsequent requests in the access log?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing exactly the same issue and it almost drove me to abandon Bottle. The phenomenon:

I can no longer access the web service after some time from startup, (serveral hours on my busy NAS, and 2-3 days on my idle Raspberry Pi), no console output, no any debug information, and the output of netstat -ntl shows clearly that the port is still being listened. Just no response from this port at all.

I finally solved this by switching the backend to **paste** by:

```py
bottle.run(server='paste')
```

as it's clarified in: https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html, maybe the default wsgiref engine is not suitable for long term running.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `gevent`

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey, signal, spawn as gspawn, socket
monkey.patch_all()
import bottle
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler

if __name__ == '__main__':
    botapp = bottle.app()
    server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", int(port)), botapp , handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    
    def shutdown():
        print('Shutting down ...')
        server.stop(timeout=60)
        exit(signal.SIGTERM)

    gevent.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown)
    gevent.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown) #CTRL C
    server.serve_forever()
```